# Limit characters of data to display on webpage with substr

Tags: php, character, limit, substr

I want to display data from my database but I have the following problem. I would like to display only the first 120 characters of the row 'text'. I know I can do this with the `substr` function.

I tried to implement `substr`in my code, but no text is shown when I reload the webpage ...

**The whole code:**

(connect to database)

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table-example`";
```

// perform the query and store the result

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$text= $row['text'];
```

// if the $result contains at least one row

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
```

// output data of each row from $result

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{?>

<div id="preview">

<div class="title">
<?php echo $row['title'];?>
</div>

<div class="subtitle">
<?php echo substr($text, 0, 120);?>
</div>

</div>

<?php  
}// end while
}// end if
else {
echo '0 results';
}
?>
```

(close connection)

Can someone please explain to me how to solve this?

Comment: The `$text` isn't set anywhere in your loop there. What about `$row['text']`? **EDIT** I see your assignment to `$text` now. You need to move that inside of your loop. That should do it.

Comment: Thanks, it works now. (Php is still new to me...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to place `$text = $row['text']` within the `while` loop.

Since before that, you don't declare `$row` to anything, therefore `$text` doesn't get set. Because `$text` isn't set, the `substr` method will shorten nothing AKA the `echo` returns nothing.

Comment: No problem, you should mark this as the solution (click the V on the left of the answer) for other people that might face the same problem ;)